# async.parallel inside async.series

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have this async.parallel functionality inside an aysnc.eachSeries call.
I hardcoded an error so I could pass it, to see if it was behaving the way I thought. For some reason, when I pass an error, it doesn't get thrown in the final callback named "doneWithSeries".

```
async.eachSeries(jsonDataArr, function iterator(item, callback) {

    async.parallel([
            function (cb) {
                if (item.hasOwnProperty('event.type')) {

                    var event_type = item['event.type'];
                    delete item['event.type'];
                    try {
                        var json = JSON.stringify(item);
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        throw err;
                    }
                    fs.writeFile('./enriched_data/' + event_type + '.json', json, function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            cb(err);
                        }
                        else {
                            cb(null);
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            function (cb) {
                if (item.hasOwnProperty('status_desc')) {

                    var status_desc = item['status_desc'];
                    delete item['status_desc'];
                    try {
                        var json = JSON.stringify(item);
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        throw err;
                    }
                    fs.writeFile('./enriched_data/' + status_desc + '.json', json, function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            cb(err);
                        }
                        else {
                            cb(null);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        ],

        function doneWithParallel(err) {
            callback(new Error('throw this baby')); //shouldn't the first incident of error pass the error straight to the doneWithSeries callback below?
        })
},
function doneWithSeries(err) {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    else {
     console.log('success');
    }
});
```

here is a distilled version of the code without anything unnecessary:

```
var async = require('async');

async.eachSeries(['1', '2'], function (item, callback) {

        async.parallel([
                function (cb) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        cb(null, 'one');
                    }, 200);
                },
                function (cb) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        cb(null, 'two');
                    }, 100);
                }
            ],
            function doneWithParallel(err, results) {
                console.log('results', results);

                callback(new Error('duh'));
            })
    },
    function doneWithSeries(err) {

        if (err)
            throw err;
    });
```

indeed that works. can't figure out why my code above doesn't, accept perhaps that the array could be empty even though when I run my code the success message gets logged...weird.

Comment: Are you sure that the `callback` line is called?

Comment: not entirely sure, if the array in eachSeries is empty it won't get called, for example; I put a distilled version of the code as an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's expected behavior if your list is empty. async will always call the final callback with no error even if there is no input list.

Comment: that may be true; but I figured out the problem, @ExplosionPills is right; the array was not empty, but I didn't put an else statement, if the item doesn't have a property, so that cb() statements were not firing in the eachSeries

Comment: I will have to delete the question since it won't help anyone